# Applying for an iphone developer certificate from scratch?

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

Just got the iphone 4 and am eager to run my 'personally built' apps on it. Have looked everywhere on the apple website, but can't see where you **'sign up for a developer certificate'**. Can someone explain to me how to do this, in baby steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to sign up for the [iOS Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).

If you don't want to pay right away, you can register as an Apple Developer for free, program your application, and try it out in the iPhone Simulator. However, you can't run your application on a real device (via *Ad Hoc Distribution*) until you pay.

Here is [Apple's development programs comparison chart](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/develop.html#compare).

Comment: Thanks! So I just bought it. I must say though that I find it a bit weird that they are shipping me something in a box. What is it?

Comment: @Eric, I'd expect some forms maybe, but I can't think of anything that would require a box.

Comment: They don't actually ship you a box, it's just apple's site giving you that message. What it's really doing is waiting for your payment and info to check out, and then emailing you your access.